# Jquery UI Datepicker MVC 4 Doesn't work C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, models

I want to include two datepicking windows in my ASP.NET Webpage. I have done everything that stands in the manual but it wont work. Please help!

This is my code :

```
@model RebeccaAndLudwig.Models.Rsvp

<head>
    <title>"Please Answer to our invite"</title>
</head>
<section id="contacts" >
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Answer</h2>
        <div class="content" style="width:700px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; letter-spacing: 1px; word-spacing:normal;">
            <h3>Here you can answer if you will come or not to our wedding, please fill everything out, otherwise we will have problems.</h3>
            <div>
                <div class="contact-form">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                        <div style="color:springgreen">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name:", new { @class = "dob" })
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FirstName, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name:", new { @class = "dob" })
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.LastName, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttendWedding, "Attend Wedding?:", new { @class = "dob" })
                            Yes
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AttendWedding, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            No
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AttendWedding, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WillStayAtHotel, "Will you stay at the hotel?:", new { @class = "dob" })
                            Yes
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.WillStayAtHotel, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            No
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.WillStayAtHotel, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HowManyNights, "How Many Nights?:", new { @class = "dob" })
                            1
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            2
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            3
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            4
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            <br />
                            5
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            6
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            7
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                            8
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HowManyNights, new { style = "width: 1000px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;" })
                        </div>
                        <div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{mm/dd/yyyy}",new {@class="datepicker"})

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, "{mm/dd/yyyy}",new {@class="datepicker"})
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Perform","Contact")" />
                            <input type="reset" value="reset" />
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

I have tried to use

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

as I thought maybe it is the styling. But no. Won't make a difference. Doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox.

**My problem is**

Is get no function on the Datepicker. I see no calendar can't choose any date. I see only a textbox.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: what happens if you load `jquery.js` first?  That should set you right.

Comment: It works, Thanks Jonesy! If  you add that as an answer I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI is built on top of jQuery, so make sure you reference jQuery first.